# Java HTTP/XML-request with special characters

Tags: java, xml, http

I'm setting up an HTTP-request to the Google geocoding API via a Java servlet. Unfortuately, everytime this request contains a special character (e.g. the 'ß'), the request returns an "Bad request / 400" exception. Since this service is about to be used in countries where these weird characters are fairly popular and neccessary - Europe - I'm having a little bit of trouble here.
Replacing the special characters with their hexadecimal escape String (0xDF/%DF for the 'ß') in the request result in a "INVALID_REQUEST" response from Google.

This is how i get the XML-response:

```
stringToReverse = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
URL urlR = new URL(url);
                URLConnection connection = urlR.openConnection();

                connection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                out.write("string=" + stringToReverse);
                out.close();

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String decodedString;
                String resultString = "";
                while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(decodedString);
                    resultString += decodedString;
                }               
                in.close();
```

Hopefully someome can help me out here. I suppose the URLConnection or one of the streams need to be set to UTF-8, considering Google's response is encoded in UTF-8 as well?!

Answer (score 0):

Use this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) for `InputStreamReader` instead:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

And also use this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) for `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, the requests still fails with a "400"-response. By the way, directly entering the request via the browser (with unescaped special characters) gives a correct result.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of `stringToReverse` which you are writing to the `outputStream`?